# Mosaic image creation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, rubygems, imagemagick

In my application, I have one functionality called **mosaic image** generation.

The detail flow is getting user's **facebook profile image** as input image. Based on the photo's 
that was **uploaded by the user and their friend's profile pictures** are input image.

Based on this i have to form a new **"mosaic image"**.

Here am using **ruby on rails application**.

Is the any gem's available to form a mosaic image?

Can any one give me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems no any straight gem/library for this mosaic image generation.But we can achieve it by RMagick gem.

Use core properties of image like pixel,resize,rgb values to replace every pixel of input image by other photos(tiles)...